# Testing whether or not a port is in use with bash and netstat?

Tags: bash, netstat, lsof

I've written a pretty long, and moderately complex Bash script that enables me to start my Node server with chosen options very easily...the problem is that it's not working correctly.

The part that is giving me trouble is here...

```
if netstat -an | grep ":$REQUESTED_PORT" > /dev/null
then
    SERVICE_PIDS_STRING=`lsof -i tcp:$REQUESTED_PORT -t`
    OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS='
    '
    read -a SERVICE_PIDS <<< "${SERVICE_PIDS_STRING}"
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"
    printf 'Port is in use by the following service(s)...\n\n-------------------\n\nProcess : PID\n\n'
    for PID in "${SERVICE_PIDS[@]}"
        do
            PROCESS_NAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm=`
            printf "$PROCESS_NAME : $PID\n"
        done
    printf "\n-------------------\n\nPlease kill the procceses utilizing port $REQUESTED_PORT and run this script again...exiting.\n"
    exit
```

The intended function of this script is to use `netstat` to test if the requested port is busy. If so, it reports the PIDs utilizing the port so that the user can kill them if they wish.

I'm fairly certain this is a problem with the way I'm using `netstat`. Occasionally, the `netstat` if statement will trigger, even though there is nothing using the port. `lsof` is working correctly, and doesn't report any PIDs using the port.

However, when the last time the script made this error, I declared the `REQUESTED_PORT` and then ran `netstat -an | grep ":$REQUESTED_PORT"`. The shell did not report anything.

What is the problem with this condition that causes it to fire at inappropriate times?

**EDIT**

I should also mention that this machine is running Debian Jessie.

Comment: While bash scripting might be categorised as programming, you might get better results for network utilities on [unix & linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BrettHale, thanks for the response. I think that you're right in that this question would be better if places in the UNIX and Linux category of StackExchange. Should I delete my question and ask again there, leave my question here and ask again there, or request that a moderator move my question?

Comment: Have you looked at the other posts in the [tag:bash] tag? This is perfectly within the scope of "programming." Indeed, why else would there be such a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching an awful lot of text, and your desired number could show up anywhere. Better to narrow the search down; and you can grab your PIDs and process names in the same step. Some other optimizations follow:

```
# upper case variable names should be reserved for the shell
if service_pids_string=$(lsof +c 15 -i tcp:$requested_port)
then
    # make an array with newline separated string containing spaces
    # note we're only setting IFS for this one command
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a service_pids <<< "$service_pids_string"
    # remove the first element containing column headers
    service_pids=("${service_pids[@]:1}")
    printf 'Port is in use by the following service(s)...\n\n-------------------\n\nProcess : PID\n\n'
    for pid in "${service_pids[@]}"
    do
        # simple space-separated text to array
        pid=($pid)
        echo "${pid[0]} : ${pid[1]}"
    done
    # printf should be passed variables as parameters
    printf "\n-------------------\n\nPlease kill the procceses utilizing port %s and run this script again...exiting.\n" $requested_port
fi
```

You should run your script through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net/); it will probably find other potential issues that I haven't.